# explorer.exe fails to load

Tags: windows-7, virus-removal

I have a VAIO notebook with Windows 7. It's a few years old. Today I wanted to start it and the Windows UI doesn't start.
Windows memory diagnostic finds no errors.

explorer.exe fails to load. The operating system is German, so I try to translate the error:

```
The application could not be started (0xc000022). 
Click on OK to close the application.
```

The first time I loaded the computer I could start opera via cmd and then go into the internet. After a bit restarting that not possible anymore.

I did run the Avira rescue CD but it didn't find any Virus.

The computer does start in safe mode. However it shows in the task bar that the Windows Security center can't be loaded. If I click on the issue it shows that I can't start the Windows Security center.

I can't restore System Points.

If this is the result of a virus, I don't see the benefit to the owner on the other side. The computer won't participate in a bot net if it doesn't load the explorer.

Furthermore given that Avira's rescue CD doesn't work what's my next step?

Comment: Are you able to boot into *System recovery mode* (Starthilfe in the German bootloader)? It's independent from the rest of your OS so using it will likely recover the original `explorer.exe`. If not, try running `sfc /scannow` to force a check of all Windows files.

Comment: @GiantTree : I don't find "Starthilfe" in the bootloader. I do find Computer Repair. In it I also have a cmd promt. If I'm typing `sfc /scannow` it tells me that a system repair is in the works and I have to restart. If I restart it still shows the same error message.

Comment: *Computer Repair* might be the thing you are searching for. Have you tried *Startup repair* (first option in "System recovery", *Systemstartreperatur*)? It fixed my last problem as well.

Comment: @GiantTree : Unfortunately Startup repair finds no errors. It seems like the error happens what Windows considers startup.